# Custom Unique ID Generation In MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to create custom id in sql table which contains below information

ID = 'SRIG'+ 'DDMMYY'+ 5 digit number.

---

Table Details

```
CREATE TABLE SR
(
    SRREQID NVARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, 
    -- Your @Entity ID might be another candidate here
    SRID INT
);
```

SQL Query

```
DECLARE @EntityId INT;
DECLARE @SRREQID NVARCHAR(100);

-- BEGIN TRAN
 SELECT @EntityId = ISNULL(MAX(SRID),0) FROM SR;

 Select @SRREQID = 'SRIC'+RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar,datepart(YY,getdate())),2)+
              RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar,datepart(MM,getdate())),2)+
              RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar,datepart(DD,getdate())),2)+                 
              RIGHT('000000'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @EntityId+1),6);

 INSERT INTO SR(SRREQID,SRID) VALUES(@SRREQID,@EntityId+1);

 SELECT * FROM SR;


-- COMMIT TRAN;
```

Query Output

```
SRREQID             SRID
SRIC160518000100    100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a computed column as well, like so:

```
create table SR
    (SRREQID AS -- Your computed column
        'SRIC'+RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar,datepart(YY,getdate())),2)+
              RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar,datepart(MM,getdate())),2)+
              RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(varchar,datepart(DD,getdate())),2)+                 
              RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), SRREQID_SEQ),5)
    , SRREQID_SEQ INT IDENTITY(1,1) -- ID used by your computed column
    , MyRandomVal varchar(25)) -- Random actual data for the table
```

Then, create a job that at precisely at the beginning of every day at 00.00 executes the following command to restart the identity of SRREQID_SEQ at 1 for the next day.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.SR', RESEED, 0);
```

There may be a smarter way to go about this, but then I haven't actually run into any scenarios where something like this would be useful, yet.

The advantage of all this is that you don't need a complex script to insert new data.

You can just insert your data normally, and the DB will automatically take care of your SRREQID for you. Like so:

```
INSERT SR (MyRandomVal) VALUES ('My data')
```

**Edit:** Also, I advise you to check Zohar Peled's comment below, where he has a suggestion that can further simplify this solution, and depending your circumstances and DB load and usage, may fit your scenario better than my suggestion above.

Comment: A Computed column is the direction I would go with. However, instead of using a job to reseed the identity column, use a udf to calculate the column, and calculate the number as `count()` of the already existing records for `getdate()`. This way, you can keep the primary key as the identity column, making your life easier.

Comment: Excellent idea. Though to be fair, this means that depending on the number of data, you'd get an index seek / scan for every single insert, so performance could become an issue at some point. Also, I'm not sure if it would be possible for two concurrent transactions to produce the same value. But logically speaking, this is a great idea. The less extra steps and maintenance (like the job in my case) that are required, the better in my book. :)

Comment: Of course, there might not even be a need to store this data in a computed column at all - if the table already have an identity column and a createdate column, you can use a view to calculate the data for this column as a part of it's select statement. Usually, though, when people talks about performance problems, it's in selects rather then inserts/updates, so...

Answer (score 1):

**For SQL Server 2012 and onward.**

At first create a [SEQUENSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.testing
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
```

Then you can run this to get new id:

```
SELECT  'SRIG' + REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),GETDATE(),4),'.','') + 
        RIGHT('0000'+CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.testing as nvarchar(5)),5)
```

Output:

```
SRIG18051600001
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to restart sequence every day then use this query:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.testing RESTART WITH 1;
```

Comment: Please note that SEQUENCE is only available from version 2012 onward. If the OP is using Sql server 2008 or lower they will need to use different mechanism to mimic a sequence (quite easy, using a table with an identity column and a stored procedure that will insert a record to it and return scope_identity())

Comment: Thanks for warning! I will put it in my answer.