# Create Table Auto Identity column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to setup an identity column to specific value with auto increment, for example `Id` column increase to 22-000001, 22-000002, etc .Next Year it should be 23-000001, 23-000002, etc
22 Year
000001 Auto increment

```
CREATE TABLE contacts 
(
    Contact_ID int IDENTITY (1,1)  not null primary key clustered 
     contact_id1 as (year(getdate()) % 100 + right ('000' + cast ( Contact_ID as varchar(3)), 3),
    Contact_name varchar(20)
)
```

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291277/custom-unique-id-generation-in-ms-sql)

Comment: Also, consider that the Identity column is meant to be an **internal** ID.  What you're asking for seems more like an external ID -- an ID that has "meaning".  You can use the Identity as a factor in your "meaningful" ID, using concepts in the links above.

Comment: Embedding values in a key like this is a bad idea and it violates 1NF by stuffing multiple values into a single tuple. This should be two columns. If you really want a column with this information in it you could create a computed column.